# DOM UTF8 Japan char set

Tags: php, character-encoding, char

I want to handle a Japanese page but will give this character error.

```
  <?php
    $profile="<div><p>イリノイ州シカゴにて、アイルランド系の家庭に、9</p></div>";
    $dom = new DomDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($profile, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
    $divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
    foreach ($divs as $div) {
        echo $dom->saveHTML($div);
    }
    //or
    $dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $profile);
    ?>
```

returned this value:

```
ã‚¤ãƒªãƒã‚¤å·ã‚·ã‚«ã‚´ã«ã¦ã€ã‚¢ã‚¤ãƒ«ãƒ©ãƒ³ãƒ‰ç³»ã®å®¶åº­ã«ã€9
```

How to fix this problem?

Update

I using simple dom parser:

```
<?php
require_once("/simple_html_dom.php");
$html = str_get_html("<p>イリノイ州シカゴにて、アイルランド系の家庭に、9</p>");
echo $html->find('p', 0)->plaintext;
?>
```

Returned ã‚¤ãƒªãƒã‚¤å·ã‚·ã‚«ã‚´ã«ã¦ã€ã‚¢ã‚¤ãƒ«ãƒ©ãƒ³ãƒ‰ç³»ã®å®¶åº­ã«ã€9

Comment: What is the Content-Type HTTP header that is being sent? Your server may be configured to send a Japanese character encoding instead of UTF-8 unless you say to use a different encoding. And what is the character encoding of your file? Have you tried explicitly specifying the from_encoding parameter when using mb_convert_encoding, using the encoding of your file? Just a few thoughts. I hope one or more helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think your php file text encoding is a EUC.
I was able to execute this program by EUC or UTF-8 only.
And,  The UTF-8 have not character encoding error.
try running if you installed the nkf.

1. check character encoding

   > nkf --guess yourfile.php
2. change character encoding

   > nkf -s ./yourfile.php > ./sjis.php
   >   nkf -e ./yourfile.php > ./euc.php
   >   nkf -w ./yourfile.php > ./utf8.php
   >   nkf -j ./yourfile.php > ./jis.php
3. those try running
   3-1. sjis.php

   > PHP Notice:  iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string in /var/www/simple_html_dom.php on line 806

   3-2. euc.php

   > �����Υ����������ˤơ������������ɷϤβ����ˡ�9

   3-3. utf8.php

   > イリノイ州シカゴにて、アイルランド系の家庭に、9

   3-4. php jis.php

   > PHP Warning:  Unexpected character in input:  '' (ASCII=27) state=0 in /var/www/jis.php on line 3
   >   PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in /var/www/jis.php on line 3

Answer (score 0):

It just the browser encode is setting "iso-8859-1" now.